# xfce4-session: Cannot open display

Tags: linux, x11, xfce

I'm trying to display XFCE4 from my phone with Termux to my PC.

I ran `xfce4-session --display=192.168.xxx.xxx:0` but it says that it cannot open display.

Here's the error:

```
No protocol specified
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: 192.168.xxx.xxx:0.
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.
```

Thanx in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`No protocol specified` usually means either:

A) you have insufficient permissions

B) the user doesn't know how to launch the application

Try this:

```
xhost +    # beware, this command gives access to anyone
xfce4-session --display=192.168.xxx.xxx:0
```